# Cropping circle from image using opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to crop circle in following image:

[image]

My code, I'm able to detect the circle but not to crop it :

```
import cv2
#import cv2.cv as cv
img1 = cv2.imread('amol.jpg')
img = cv2.imread('amol.jpg',0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 200)
#cv2.imshow('detected ',gray)
cimg=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10000, param1 = 50, param2 = 30, minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 0)
for i in circles[0,:]:
    i[2]=i[2]+4
    cv2.circle(img1,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)

#Code to close Window
cv2.imshow('detected Edge',img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Hey there. SO is not a "How To" site, so you will need to edit this question and show what you have tried, what is and isn't working, and ask a specific question based on that.

Comment: I used google for you: http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2014/02/crop-elliptical-region-from-image.html

translate to python

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**1. Create a mask:**

```
height,width = img.shape
mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)
```

**2. Draw the circles on that mask (set thickness to -1 to fill the circle):**

```
circle_img = cv2.circle(mask,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,255),thickness=-1)
```

**3. Copy that image using that mask:**

```
masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img1, mask=circle_img)
```

**4. Apply Threshold**

```
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

**5. Find Contour**

```
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
```

**6. Crop masked_data**

```
crop = masked_data[y:y+h,x:x+w]
```

#### Adding this to your code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('amol.jpg')
img = cv2.imread('amol.jpg',0)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Create mask
height,width = img.shape
mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)

edges = cv2.Canny(thresh, 100, 200)
#cv2.imshow('detected ',gray)
cimg=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edges, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 10000, param1 = 50, param2 = 30, minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 0)
for i in circles[0,:]:
    i[2]=i[2]+4
    # Draw on mask
    cv2.circle(mask,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,255),thickness=-1)

# Copy that image using that mask
masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(img1, img1, mask=mask)

# Apply Threshold
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find Contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])

# Crop masked_data
crop = masked_data[y:y+h,x:x+w]

#Code to close Window
cv2.imshow('detected Edge',img1)
cv2.imshow('Cropped Eye',crop)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

#### Result using your image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was quite helpful. Now can be extract only the circular portion and make the background part transparent?