# Cropping Circle with Hough Transform using OpenCV Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, hough-transform, iris-recognition

I want to crop circle from iris image in following below:

[image: Example of iris image detection using hough circle]

and this is my code for circle detection:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

gambar = cv2.imread('tes2.jpg',0)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(gambar,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
canny = cv2.Canny(cimg,50,50)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(canny,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10000,
                    param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=50,maxRadius=200)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[2]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[2]),2,(0,0,255),3)

plt.imshow(cimg,cmap = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

but, I don't know how to crop this circle (iris localization). I have been following this code reference [Cropping circle from the image using OpenCV python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911877/cropping-circle-from-image-using-opencv-python#). And this is my code below for crop image:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2

gambar1 =cv2.imread('tes2.jpg') 
gambar = cv2.imread('tes2.jpg',0)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(gambar,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(cimg, 50, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Create mask
height,width = gambar.shape
mask = np.zeros((height,width), np.uint8)

canny = cv2.Canny(thresh,100,200)


gray = cv2.cvtColor(gambar,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(canny,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10000,
                    param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)


for i in circles[0,:]:
    cv2.circle(mask,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(255,255,255),thickness=-1)

masked_data = cv2.bitwise_and(gambar1, gambar1, mask=mask)

# Apply Threshold
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(mask,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find Contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])

# Crop masked_data
crop = masked_data[y:y+h,x:x+w]

plt.imshow(gambar1,cmap = 'gray')
plt.imshow(crop, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

but, when I try this code such as reference above, I get an error like this:

```
File "C:/Users/zurri/spyder/masktes.py", line 14, in <module>
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(gambar,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: OpenCV(4.2.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
Invalid number of channels in input image:
     'VScn::contains(scn)'
 where
     'scn' is 1
```

anyone can help me to fix this problem? I just want to crop this circle (iris localization) using openCV python, thank you

Comment: The error message says `'scn' is 1`. This means that the number of channels in the source image is 1. You use `gambar = cv2.imread('tes2.jpg',0)` to read the source image. The 0 means to read the image as grayscale, i.e. a 1-channel image. Since you read the image as grayscale, there is no need to convert it to grayscale.

Comment: I see, thank you, it is work!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

***Explanation***

---

`findContours` method retrieves the contours from the given binary image using [Suzuki's](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/38698235/suzuki1985.pdf?1441687436=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DTopological_Structural_Analysis_of_Digit.pdf&Expires=1599164806&Signature=KmLJn3HPuJ4yPxFtLbet5mnIUT77zfQS-46eqzE1siuDYl4jBl%7EuUSNJ4uCP1I7r5xUNW2WIHhNnG3kCuzs-f2jrsJSp0F65LacYj3cZkkl%7EI4LzDBnJ0dIR1xNcjjOPjhi%7E5FPsZa19fvpnKYSJxHzxN7SgJFOY2XeDrBZ1EDXmXe1doFZps2Xu%7ErQyzfEESsjACbDNzj9fe1fQqKWEm9NLg3J81NTg0vhweLnO%7Ek6ZUrsXdx1-Ao4zQobEcrieislEL6zeIYa-73m9Fj0apeAElhfLcAVUgrMrBoRV5WqFIRbeofnNyEPYl3NClitcbj1NckakOZ0m1Y2ZvYxJCw__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA) algorithm. Contours are useful for shape analysis, object detection and recognition.

The `findContour` method returns two variables: `contours` and `hierarchy`. In the original code you did `contours = cv2.findContour(...)` in which you combines both `contours` and `hierarchy` variables. Therefore you had an error. We simply don't need `hieararchy` variable, therefore we placed `_`. So the error was resolved.

***Solution***

---

Replace the `findContours` line with the below:

```py
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thank you for advance. but, I want to crop iris, not pupil. What line can I change ?

Comment: You can use [iris-recognition](https://pypi.org/project/G6-iris-recognition/) library